# How to quickly find the required header files for a given declaration in Visual Studio / C++ / .NET?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010, header-files

I am trying to compile a Visual Studio / C++ code snippet I have found on the internet containing the function:

```
Marshal::SizeOf()
```

When compiling the snippet, I get the error message:

```
error C2653: 'Marshal' : is not a class or namespace name
```

so I think I need to include a header file with the definition of this namespace or class, and the SizeOf() function.

When I look up `Marshal::SizeOf` `C++` in Google I find [this help page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3ybkfb3.aspx), however on this page there is no information regarding which header file must be included in order to use this function.

Is there a documentation page where one can look up all .NET classes and functions and easily find the C++ header file that must be included in order to use them?

Comment: Click on `Marshal` and press ctrl+. (This may be C# specific in VS, but worth a shot)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, do you mean "mouse left-click" followed by 'ctrl' combined with '+'?

Comment: I mean "mouse left-click" followed by 'ctrl' combined with '.' (a period)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand what C++/CLI is. It is a proprietary extension to C++ by Microsoft to make the interfacing between native and managed code (i.e. .Net) easy.

`Marshal` is not a C++ class, it's a C++/CLI class. As such, there's no header to include. It's `#import` you are looking for.

Comment: My project is C++ only, maybe I shouldn't be using Marshal::SizeOf() at all? I.e. I should look for another code snippet for the problem I was trying to solve.

Comment: Yes, should not then. The closest C++ equivalent is `sizeof()`, though you'll need to precise your use case for a more precise answer.